# Is there a way to use getchar() in vim without a need to press enter after every input key?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, getchar

I'm writing a vim plugin and use `getchar()` to get input keys, however it requires me to essentially double press every key I want to type. My end goal here is to get keyboard input as a keylogger would, but only for vim so after that I could analyse the data.

Sadly couldn't make suggestions from https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Wait_for_user_input_(getchar)_without_moving_cursor work.

This is a piece of code from my plugin:

```
function! s:getchar()
  let chr = getchar()
  if chr =~ '^\d\+$'
    let chr = nr2char(chr)
  endif
  python3 sample.gather()
endfunction

au CursorMoved * call s:getchar()
```

So far I use python only to put timestamp next to the key that was pressed.

I did quite a research on this topic, but was unable to find a solution on how to utilize `getchar()` in vim properly.

Comment: `getchar()` doesn't require pressing `<CR>` at all.

Comment: Perhaps, you could also explain why simple "q" is not good for you.

Comment: @Matt Does q have timestamps? I'll read more about it, thank you. I need timestamps in order to distinguish, for example: "jjj" typed without delays and the same sequence, but with 1 minute interval or whatever, cause there is a difference!

Comment: @romainl well it sends you to the command mode and waits for a key to be typed, that's what I meant

Comment: @SumLare, that's still one single key to press.

Comment: @romainl wait how so? I press a key to trigger it -> it goes to command mode I press another key and only then it's over

Comment: @SumLare the key press that triggered your autocommand has nothing to do with`getchar()`. If you don't want that first key press, then you will have to find another way to do `getchar()` that doesn't involve pressing a key.

Comment: @romainl oh I see, got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> "My end goal here is to get keyboard input as a keylogger would, but only for vim so after that I could analyse the data."

Vim has an option, `-w {scriptout}` for recording keypresses to a file `{scriptout}`.

For converting the raw data to a human-readable representation, there's [an example](https://github.com/dstein64/vimgolf/blob/f585cf4a6fe5b1c497b871b8b2bf1ac0da21c7a8/vimgolf/vimgolf.py#L455-L467) in the [Python vimgolf client](https://github.com/dstein64/vimgolf) that I implemented.

The [official vimgolf client](https://github.com/igrigorik/vimgolf/tree/0828afaf1b858fc9cfa9e57106abecf1fd172e51/lib/vimgolf), implemented in Ruby, also utilizes Vim's `-w` option for recording keypresses.

I know this doesn't answer the specific question about `getchar()`, but I thought it might be a workaround given the stated end goal.

Comment: Thank you for the example link, the problem is that makes analysis harder, for example it becomes hard to separate coherent commands like `gg` or `g + g` without timestamps, but may be that problem can be solved even without timestamp